# Rails before_create callback usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have fairly simple problem but I can not think of the simple solution.  I have 3 models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :school
end

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
end
```

A User can create a membership for school(s). "membernumber" is given by school. So far so good.

Except one use case, where a membership record gets created by school without user_id value in memberships table.

In this case a record gets created with "membernumber", "school_id" and empty "user_id" field.

What I want to do is, when a user tries to create his membership (using his "membernumber") with a school, First I want to see if "user_id", "membernumber". school_id combination is unique if found (I used validates_uniqueness_of....).

If record not found than check a record/association with "membernumber" and school exists and it's user_id field is empty. If that is the case then don't create a new membership but just update it's user_id field (with current_user.id) and return with a msg that a creation of new association is successful (as if its a new membership record).

How do I do this? Do I need to use any callbacks? How do I use callbacks in this case?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Atarangp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it.
In model membership, added a method membership_exists and called it from membership's create
 action.

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  belongs_to :user
  #validations, etc.

  def Membership.membership_exists(membernumber, school_id)
     membership = Membership.where(:membernumber =>  membernumber, :school_id => school_id, :user_id => nil).first
     if membership.nil?
        return false
     else
        membership.update_attribute :user_id, user_id
        return true
     end
  end
end
```

And in Membership controller (in create action)

```
  def create
    @membership = Membership.new(params[:membership])
    @membership.user_id = current_user.id

    @flag = Membership.membership_exists(@membership.membernumber,@membership.school_id)
    if @flag == true
      flash[:notice] = "Membership creation is successful"
      redirect_to @membership
      return
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @membership.save
        format.html { redirect_to @membership, notice: 'Membership was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @membership, status: :created, location: @membership }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @membership.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

This works. But is it a good way to do it?

Thanks,
Atarangp.

Answer (score 3):

You should enforce uniqueness constraints in your migrations as well, however much DHH like's to preach the slathering of 'dumb persistance' across the board and only handle this at the application level.

The simplest approach is to enforce `validates_presence_of :user_id` in your `Membership` model.  This will not allow join-records to be created if a user ID isn't present; your AR associative queries should inherently pass this ID on anyways.

For example, consider - `User.last.memberships.build(@school)` and in the context of your application, the User will be the `current_user` itself.

`before_create` and other `before_` AR callbacks are definitely handy, but I'd always leave such an approach as a last resort.  The reason is you'd intuitively expect your app to function in a certain manner whilst these `before_` callbacks, can essentially mutate the information hitting the DB.  Of course, unit tests will take care of such issues.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, migration does has have uniqueness test using validates_presence_of :user_id, :scope => [:memberid, :school_id].  But I do want to be able to create join record without user_id field set. The idea is that this record gets connected with a user when he/she tries to create membership. In my use case such a record gets created by a cron job.

Answer (score 1):

Only going by the models, one can make out:

1. Membership contains references of both, User and School, and can hence act as a join table for a `has_and_belongs_to_many` or a `has_many :through` relationship between User and School
2. If we consider the above, then any Membership record has a valid existence if and only if it is able to refer both, a User and a School. Somehow, I could not think of a use case where you would *want* to create a Membership record without a reference to the User. It would be great if you could elaborate a little on your use-case.

If the above works for you, then your models shall look something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :schools, :through => :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :school
end

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end
```

Now, you should be able to add users to a school and vice-versa.

```
user = User.first
user.schools << School.first
```

This would automatically create a record in Membership with appropriate references. And the user would start showing up in `School.first.users`. Further, you could add validations for uniqueness within the scope of a school_id i.e. `validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :school_id` .

before_ after_ callbacks are good but in this case, you'll need some custom code for keeping things in sync. The above would eliminate any dependency on before_ after_ callbacks. Also, you wouldn't need to bother about any other validation checks on Membership model since the record would be created automatically only when a User record is added to a School record and vice-versa.

Comment: Yes, your models and the whole explanation is correct. But in this use case where a membership record gets created only with membernumber and school_id for a user who is not yet signed up with the system. This is a special case. And to handle this case while creating this record I used admin_user.id to be saved instead of keeping user_id field empty. This solves the case where no membership record without user_id exists. So now when a real user logs in and try to create his membership, I want to search given membernumber, school_id and user_id=admin_user.id and just updates it's user_id.

Comment: The reason I need to do this so that any satellite data associated with membership_id (other than school_id) will remain accessible to the real user. May be I could use after_save callback, to update the membership_id field in all the associated models which has_many_and_belongs_to relation with this membership and destroy old membership record with admin_user.id. Will this be the best solution? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Is 'membernumber', an attribute of Membership? If yes, then you could still add a record without a user_id and search for the record by it's 'membernumber' later. Finally, you could associate the user to this record. You wouldn't need to store an admin_id with it. user_id could be nil in that case. You can search a Membership record using a dynamic finder Membership.find_by_membernumber_and_school_id(some_member_number, school) . Uniqueness validation mentioned in my answer shall avoid any duplicates. Please let me know if this helps! :)

Comment: rhetonik, Thanks. And yes that's what I need to do, but how can I do that? I need to do this check in membership create method but before actually creating it? Where do I do this check and update if necessary? Do I need to write before_create callback?